# Why need Java Modules to structuring projects?

Tags: java

I can't understand importance of java modules. What's problem with plain structuring with packages?

P.S. Apologise for maybe stupid questition.

Comment: I'm sure you've read a lot about modules before asking this; so, what were the specific points raised in your research that you need clarification about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modularity adds a higher level of aggregation above packages. The key new language element is the module—a uniquely named, reusable group of related packages, as well as resources.

You can check read more details here: 
https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html

Hope it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered good-quality, because they don't highlight specific things in the linked pages, and are useless if the link dies. Please improve your answer by quoting salient parts of the pages.